# How to retrieve the text entered in a text field using webdriver (python)?

Tags: python, webdriver

This is a really basic question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere... How do I retrieve the text entered in a text field using webdriver under python? I have tried several  `text` and `text()` neither works.

```
>>> driver.get("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
>>> el = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[contains(@name, 'search')]")
>>> el
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x10d15f6d0>]
>>> el[0].send_keys("orange") # this works
>>> el[0].text
''
>>> el[0].text()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> el[0].get_text()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if that works (because I couldn't test it) but maybe try to get the content of the value-attribute. It seems to me that the entered text is in the value-attribute.

Comment: ding ding ding `el[0].get_attribute("value")` does it, thanks! If you reply in an answer I can accept it with a check mark...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I investigated the search element on the Wikipedia site with firebug it seems to me that the entered text value is stored in the value-attribute. So you have to get this attribute.

Answer (score 11):

As i have been using attribute action only. it was working fine to me.Use this code below.            which text need to get from inputs

```
Description=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='id_description']")
Description.clear()
Description.send_keys("xxx")
Description.get_attribute("xxxx")
print Description
```